# Unable to create a constant value of type. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported

Tags: c#, entity-framework, primitive

I have an entity like the following :

```
class Serial {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string No { get; set; }
}
```

what I have to get is a list of serials by a list of serial ids, but continuously I get the error :

```
 Unable to create a constant value of type ProjectName.Models.Serial. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported.
```

this is what I've written so far :

```
List<Serial> serials = _ctx.Serials.Where(s => sList.Any(ss => ss.Id == s.Id)).ToList();
```

and

```
List<Serial> serials = _ctx.Serials.Where(s => sList.Select(ss => ss.Id).Contains(s.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as this

```
var ids =  List<int> { 324,54,234,645};

Var serialized = _ctx.Serials.Where(s => ids.Contains(s.Id)).ToList();
```

[Enumerable.Contains Method (IEnumerable, TSource)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Determines whether a sequence contains a specified element by using
>   the default equality comparer.